# C# Monodroid Event Handlers

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

How do I operate the event handlers in C# Monodroid using:

```
m_listView.OnTouchEvent += OnTouchEvent;
```

It doesn't work as it would for a button or an item, and it gives an error:

> "Cannot Assign to OnTouchEvent because it is a method group".

Comment: Try `m_listView.OnTouchEvent += new YourDelegateType(OnTouchEvent);` assuming implicit method group conversion not implemented in monodroid, atleast in the version which you use.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, no, your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: I also tried the .touch event - m_listView.Touch += new EventHandler<Android.Views.View.TouchEventArgs>(OnTouchListEventE); then i got a further error telling me no match for delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like choper said that method is one you would override on a custom view. To subscribe to the touch event you should use Touch instead:

```
        m_listView.Touch += HandleTouch;
    }

    void HandleTouch (object sender, View.TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        // e.Event => MotionEvent
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not event at all, it just a method so the code that you provided should not work at all. You can override this method if  you create custom `ListView` but you can not subscribe on it as on an event